# Sunburst effect with css3 gradient

Tags: css, sass, gradient

I have been looking around and trying for a few days, but i just cant seem to get it 100% right... i am trying to achieve the following effect with css3 gradient:

[image: sunburst done in illustrator]

the closest i have gotten is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/1xLxmbsg/)**:

```css
html {
  background:
    linear-gradient(80deg, transparent 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd),
    linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd),
    linear-gradient(82deg, transparent 50%, #eee 50%, #eee),
    linear-gradient(67deg, transparent 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd),
    linear-gradient(52deg, transparent 50%, #eee 50%, #eee),
    linear-gradient(37deg, transparent 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd),
    linear-gradient(22deg, transparent 50%, #eee 50%, #eee),
    linear-gradient(7deg, transparent 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd),
    linear-gradient(-8deg, transparent 50%, #eee 50%, #eee),
    linear-gradient(-23deg, transparent 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd),
    linear-gradient(-38deg, transparent 50%, #eee 50%, #eee),
    linear-gradient(-53deg, transparent 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd),
    linear-gradient(-68deg, transparent 50%, #eee 50%, #eee),
    linear-gradient(-83deg, transparent 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd);
  background-position: center -100%;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

I will continue attempting it.. any help is greatly Appreciated though.

**Update:**

There has to be a better/reusable way of doing this... looking into a scss solution, here is what i have thus far:

```
.sunburst {
  @for $ray from 1 through 26 {
    $color: #eee;
    $degree: 7;
    @if $ray%2 == 0 {
      $color: #ddd;
    }
    background:linear-gradient($degree+deg, transparent 50%, $color 50%, $color),
  }
}
```

Now its just the actual maths behind it i am trying to figure out... attempting to steal logic from [pow.js](https://github.com/greim/pow.js), but kind of difficult if your as terrible at maths as i am...

Comment: I've converted your demo into a Stack Overflow code snippet. (Don't worry, I've kept the JSFiddle link there too).

Comment: wow thanks, wasn't aware of stack overflow snippets.. haven't been here in a while.

Comment: thanks @user2570380 but i am looking for something thats a little bit easier on older browsers.. i did come across that though...

Comment: So you've changed your question from "how do I make this effect in CSS" to "how do I programatically generate this CSS with Sass"?  Please don't do this if you've already received answers, ask a different question instead.

Comment: @cimmanon no not at all.. i will still accept the answer to the original question.. but i will however post the sass solution (when i one day figure it out) too..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `:before` and `:after` :pseudo-elements to get this effect.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#grad {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#grad:after, #grad:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, black 50%, black), linear-gradient(82deg, transparent 50%, #12E0DB 50%, #12E0DB), linear-gradient(67deg, transparent 50%, #000000 50%, #000000), linear-gradient(52deg, transparent 50%, #12E0DB 50%, #12E0DB), linear-gradient(37deg, transparent 50%, #000000 50%, #000000), linear-gradient(22deg, transparent 50%, #12E0DB 50%, #12E0DB), linear-gradient(7deg, transparent 50%, #000000 50%, #000000), linear-gradient(-8deg, transparent 50%, #12E0DB 50%, #12E0DB), linear-gradient(-23deg, transparent 50%, #000000 50%, #000000), linear-gradient(-38deg, transparent 50%, #12E0DB 50%, #12E0DB), linear-gradient(-53deg, transparent 50%, #000000 50%, #000000), linear-gradient(-68deg, transparent 50%, #12E0DB 50%, #12E0DB), linear-gradient(-83deg, transparent 50%, #000000 50%, #000000), linear-gradient(-90deg, transparent 50%, #12E0DB 50%, #12E0DB);
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
#grad:before {
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="grad"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

In modern chrome-based browsers there are conic gradients which do this.

```css
       div {
       height:250px;
          background-image:
             repeating-conic-gradient(#fff 0 9deg, #000 9deg 18deg);
        }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: While a clean and certainly good solution, as of April '20 there is still no support for `repeating-conic-gradient` in Firefox (See [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_types_image_gradient_repeating-conic-gradient) and [the now five(!) year old bug on BugZilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1175958))

Comment: Now, May 2021, Firefox now supports this. Very nice, simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your `background-postition` is set to `center -100%;`. Just use

```
background-position: center center;
```

Now with this change and your provided code half of your image is already done ;). Just add the second half with more `linear-gradients`

Comment: well spotted, i  am carrying on but damn, its hard to keep track.. thanks again though.

Answer (score 0):

**@chipChocolate.py** gave a brilliant solution! This is an improvement based on his.

1. In Firefox `transparent` behaves like `rgba(0,0,0,0)` which leaves a thin gray line at the edge. Change to `rgba(255,255,255,0)` looks better.
2. Make the visual effect closer to OP's screenshot: 36 strips, each occupies a 10 degree angle.
3. Effective on `<html>` tag, like OP's try.

BTW: Chrome's render engine sucks, best viewed in Firefox.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

html:before, html:after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(85deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #12e0db 50%, #12e0db),
                    linear-gradient(75deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #000 50%, #000),
                    linear-gradient(65deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #12e0db 50%, #12e0db),
                    linear-gradient(55deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #000 50%, #000),
                    linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #12e0db 50%, #12e0db),
                    linear-gradient(35deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #000 50%, #000),
                    linear-gradient(25deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #12e0db 50%, #12e0db),
                    linear-gradient(15deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #000 50%, #000),
                    linear-gradient(5deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #12e0db 50%, #12e0db),
                    linear-gradient(-5deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #000 50%, #000),
                    linear-gradient(-15deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #12e0db 50%, #12e0db),
                    linear-gradient(-25deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #000 50%, #000),
                    linear-gradient(-35deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #12e0db 50%, #12e0db),
                    linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #000 50%, #000),
                    linear-gradient(-55deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #12e0db 50%, #12e0db),
                    linear-gradient(-65deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #000 50%, #000),
                    linear-gradient(-75deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #12e0db 50%, #12e0db),
                    linear-gradient(-85deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #000 50%, #000),
                    linear-gradient(-95deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #12e0db 50%, #12e0db);
}

html:before {
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is a `repeating-conic-gradient`, which creates an image consisting of a repeating gradient.

```css
div {
  height: 500px;
  background: repeating-conic-gradient(
    hsl(186deg 100% 50% / 31%) 0deg 15deg,
    hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 0deg 30deg
  ) #1c2c3c
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

You read more about it at [W3 CSS Image Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-images-4/#example-34b67cf2).
This property is not compatible with all browsers. Check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-conic-gradients)  for more information.